# Adding apostrophe in array list in php

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have this code for the breadcrumbs on my wordpress site:

```
$breadcrump_title23 = get_the_title();
if(in_array(strtolower($breadcrump_title23), array('dairy','delicatessen',
   'oils & fats', 'confectionery & bakery','fruits & vegetables','cereals',
   'ingredients','lpg','mil','selection du chef','tara','fleur d'or',
   'vita vanaspati','vita ghee','parmalat','bridel','butterfly','alshifa,'cebe',
   'sally williams','royal dansk','gouty','switz','banquet d'or','classico',
   'mydibel','fruitace','purejoy','tia's','csm bakery solutions','lesaffre',total',))){
  $breadcrump_title23 = 'Quality Food';
} else {
  $breadcrump_title23 = get_the_title();
}
/*-*/
```

The problem is all the values without apostrophe changes correctly, the ones with apostrophe doesn't change at all.
I tried tia\'s or "tia's" for example but nothing happens.

Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code

```
//Hope this is a custom array for checking.
$checkArray = array(
                    "dairy","delicatessen","oils & fats", 
                    "confectionery & bakery","fruits & vegetables",
                    "cereals","ingredients","lpg","mil",
                    "selection du chef","tara","fleur d'or",
                    "vita vanaspati","vita ghee","parmalat","bridel",
                    "butterfly","alshifa","cebe","sally williams","royal dansk",
                    "gouty","switz","banquet d'or",
                    "classico","mydibel","fruitace",
                    "purejoy","tia's","csm bakery solutions","lesaffre","total"
                    );
//$checkArray = array_map('addslashes', $checkArray); // Add Slashes to single quotes
$checkArray = array_map('strtolower', $checkArray);

$breadcrump_title23 =  strtolower(trim(stripslashes( get_the_title() )));

if(in_array(strtolower($breadcrump_title23),$checkArray)){
    $breadcrump_title23 = 'Quality Food';
}else {
    $breadcrump_title23 = get_the_title();
}
```

Comment: Still the same, it still gives me the title tia's instead of quality food.
http://quality.digitalnead.com/food/tias/

On this one, without the apostrophe, it still works fine:http://quality.digitalnead.com/food/lavazza-2/

Comment: can you `echo $breadcrump_title23;` before the in_array checking in both cases?

Comment: @DarrylLouis I have made a change to the code, Can you check again?

Comment: Ah just saw your comment, gonna check it back

Comment: Tried again, with no luck. Still the same

Comment: Can you echo then the $breadcrump_title23; before the in_array

Comment: I added it here - it just displayed the current title before the breadcrumbs on the frontend
`code`
echo $breadcrump_title23;
if(in_array(strtolower($breadcrump_title23),$checkArray)){
    $breadcrump_title23 = 'Quality Food';
}else {
    $breadcrump_title23 = get_the_title();
}`code`

Comment: Echo prints on your page ?  and  does it have a value that exists inside $checkArray  array ?

Comment: Yes it printed on the page, check here: http://quality.digitalnead.com/food/tias/
The value is tia's in the array we created I suppose.
I'm not a full stack dev, I just know some of the basics and logics behind some things by the way. The array was already present when I took the site to modify but at that time nothing had apostrophe

Comment: @DarrylLouis Issue got , `Tia's had capital T` , I have added a strtolower before trip also, Can you try that too please , I hope it should solve the issue

Comment: :(  Does is overriding fom somewhere else ? Can ou add the same $breadcrump_title23 = 'Quality Food';  to else also for checking that:   Code seems to be 100% fine, I checked with test data.. So a try and find error should performed

Comment: Well normally that data is the default wordpress breacrumbs title when creating pages. Added to the else, it changes correctly but since it is in the else, it changes the other pages as well

Comment: Have an idea but not sure if you might know the way around it - if you create and IF statement that checks if it is a child of the page id of Food inside the else. however the page id might not be the same on the actual site, this one is a test copy